# Getting JSON Object from API using POST

Tags: android

I want to send GET Request to get data for my application but the website only has POST  Request to get the JSON raw file. It said I need to put the api as `HEADER` but usually in retrofit I just pass it as a parameter. What is the problem here?

Comment: Share your code, what you have did so far.

Comment: Tried to use Header(<api-goes-here>) annotation just above POST annotation on the retrofit interface and it's showing error. So far that is the only code. I also tried to access it on a browser but it said i need to put api key in my header. I don't know what a header is. @Shane

Comment: Add your API code in the post, not in the comment

Comment: are you using java or kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **post** request in **Retrofit** try code like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("CUSTOM_URL")
Call<ResponseBody> customMethodName(
  @Header("custom_header") String customHeader,
  @Field("custmom_field_as_body") int customFieldAsBody
);
```

I think you have forgotten to add the **annotation** top of request.

Answer (score 0):

Declare you APIs like this :

```
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
```

or

```
@GET("users/repos")
Call<List<Repo>> listRepos();
```

then call this like :

```
Call< List<Repo> > call = movieApiService.listRepos(API_KEY);
call.enqueue(new Callback< List<Repo> >() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call< List<Repo> > call, Response< List<Repo> > response) {
List<Repo> data = response.body();
Log.d(TAG, "Number of data received: " + data.size());
}
```

For more info try this link https://android.jlelse.eu/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-in-android-ed47aef01ecb

Comment: So you have to first create `Repo` right? Does it use `SeralizedName` on top of it's variables?

Comment: No just write @Expose